# How to send argument when init UIView

Tags: swift

Its been asked before but without a coherent simple answer.

Usually you do :

```
override init (frame : CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame : frame)
```

I **need** to do (which I can't because there is no such function to override) :

```
override init (frame : CGRect, number:Int)
{
    super.init(frame : frame)
```

Which obviously gives a few errors.
Is there a way to **create instances as usual** and still pass arguments ?

Comment: Read the error message: You *don't override any method from its super class*, that means there is no initializer `init(frame: number:)` in the super class. Replace `override` with `convenience`.

Comment: That will produce more errors, can you post please a direct answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fulfill all rules and requirements you have to write

```
class MyView : UIView {

    var number : Int

    override convenience init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        self.init(frame:frame, number: 0)
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, number: Int)
    {
        self.number = number
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        number = 0
        super.init(coder : aDecoder)
    }
}
```

It might be easier to initialize the view the usual / designated way and set the property in an extra line.

Answer (score 1):

There's no override method for the one that you specified, just write it like this

```
init(frame : CGRect, number: Int) {
    super.init(frame : frame)
}
```

Comment: Instead the original override ? and you initialize it as usual ?

Comment: If you do it the way that I've described here, you'll be creating a custom initializer but you need to call the `super.init(frame:)` in your custom initializer, so that you can pass the frame from your custom init to the super.

Comment: Thats I already know :) I was looking for a way to do this in one line when I initiate the class as usual . Did I get you wrong ?

Comment: If your adding a new initializer which is not inherited from the superclass you should not add the keyword override before it, because it does not exist in the superclass.